# Set deep property on bean, creating intermediary instances if needed

Tags: java, javabeans, apache-commons-beanutils

I'm using BeanUtils.setProperty to set deep properties on a bean.

```
Home home = new Home() ;
String path = "home.family.father.age";
Integer value = 40;

BeanUtils.setProperty(home, path, value);
// Does the same as home.getHome().getFamily().getFather().setAge(value);
// But stops on null (instead of throwing an NPE).
```

The behavior of BeanUtils is to do nothing if one of the intermediary properties is `null`. So for example in my case, `home`'s `family` property is `null`, and nothing happens. If I do

```
family = new Family();
```

Then `father` will be null and I'd have to initialize it too. Obviously my real use case is more complex, with many dynamic properties (and also indexed ones).

Is there a way to tell BeanUtils to instantiate intermediate members ? I know that in general this is not possible (because the concrete type of a property may not be known). But in my case all properties have concrete types and are proper beans (with a public no-args constructor). So it would be possible.

I'd like to make sure there aren't already existing solutions (using BeanUtils or something else) for this before rolling my own.

Answer (score 2):

I rolled my own. It only supports simple properties but I guess adding support for nested/mapped properties wouldn't be too hard.

Here is a gist in case anyone needs the same thing:
https://gist.github.com/ThomasGirard/7115693

And here's what the most important part looks like:

```
/** Mostly copy-pasted from {@link PropertyUtilsBean.setProperty}. */
public void initProperty(Object bean, String path) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException,
        IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

    // [...]

    // If the component is null, initialize it
    if (nestedBean == null) {

        // There has to be a method get* matching this path segment
        String methodName = "get" + StringUtils.capitalize(next);
        Method m = bean.getClass().getMethod(methodName);

        // The return type of this method is the object type we need to init.
        Class<?> propType = m.getReturnType();
        try {
            // Since it's a bean it must have a no-arg public constructor
            Object newInst = propType.newInstance();
            PropertyUtils.setProperty(bean, next, newInst);
            // Now we have something instead of null
            nestedBean = newInst;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new NestedNullException("Could not init property value for '" + path + "' on bean class '"
                    + bean.getClass() + "'. Class: " + propType);
        }
    }

    // [...]

}
```